# PHP - database column data query returning another columns data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am writing a basic PHP login system for a school project, I am currently trying to implement email activation. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
        $query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email
            useractivestatus
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 

    // The parameter values 
    $parameters = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        // Execute the query against the database 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($parameters); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $err) 
    { 

        die("Failed to run query: " . $err->getMessage()); 
    } 
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row) 
    {
    if($active != $row['useractivestatus'] );
    {
        die("Account has not been activated");
    }
```

The problem is using var_dump$row['useractivestatus'] I can see it always returns the data from the email column, causing the query to always return false and trigger the die response. I can do var_dump$row['*any other column*'] and it returns the correct data. why is the it returning the email when querying the useractivestatus column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma in your query, as such email is actually aliased as useractivestatus and trying to select from the email column would fail.

```
$query = " 
SELECT 
    id, 
    username, 
    password, 
    salt, 
    email, -- this comma was missing
    useractivestatus
FROM users 
WHERE 
    username = :username
```

Comment: happens to us all, happy coding :)